# jQuery conact variable input name not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a "click to add another" event, this variable tracks the index of the dynamically generated element:

`var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().index();`

which works correctly, as evidenced through console logging.  The minimum value of the `index` variable is 1, no maximum.  I create a copy of the original html snippet and append it below, with replaced input names (so I can run jQuery validate):

```
$("[name=officeAddressLine1]:last").replaceWith("<input type='text' data-
id='"+index+"' class='otherBusinessField' id='officeAddressLine"+index+"'
name='officeAddressLine"+index+"'>");
```

I am concatenating the value of `index` to make the input unique, and for the first dynamically generated element, I get `officeAddressLine2` (which is correct) but all elements after that keep on concatenating a 2, as opposed to 3, 4, 5,...

All the while I am able to log the correct value of `index` on the click event.  Why won't this value update when inside of the input tag?

Here is the jQuery event handler:

```
$('#BusinessBox').on('click', '.otherOffices [value=y]', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().attr('name') == 'otherOffice'){
        return false;
    }
    var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().index();
    var template = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().html().replace(/name="otherOfficeRadio\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/id="otherOfficeRadioYes\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/id="emailProcessedByMe\d+"/g, function(str) {
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/for="emailProcessedByMe\d+"/g, function(str) {
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });

    template = template.replace(/id="emailProcessedByStaff\d+"/g, function(str) {
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/for="emailProcessedByStaff\d+"/g, function(str) {
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });


    template = template.replace(/id="weelChairAccessible\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/for="weelChairAccessible\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/id="twoBlocksFromPublicTransport\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/for="twoBlocksFromPublicTransport\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });


    template = template.replace(/id="otherOfficeRadioNo\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/for="otherOfficeRadioNo\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    template = template.replace(/for="otherOfficeRadioYes\d+"/g, function(str) {
        //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', str).remove();
        return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
            return ++n;
        });
    });
    // console.log(template);
    //$('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch', template).remove();
    $('[name=otherOffice]:last').after($('<div name="otherOffice" class="yellow_sec textBlock">' + template.replace(/style=".*?"/g, '').replace(/Primary/g, 'Additional').replace(/(Additional\s\w+)\s\d*/g, '$1 ' + index + ' ') + '</div>').hide().fadeIn());

    console.log(index, "INDEX");
    //BEGIN change input names for other business location for validation
    $("[name=officeAddressLine1]:last").replaceWith("<input type='text' data-id='"+index+"' class='otherBusinessField' id='officeAddressLine"+index+"' name='officeAddressLine"+index+"'>");
    $("[name=city]:last").replaceWith("<input type='text' class='otherBusinessField' data-id='"+index+"' id='city"+index+"' name='city"+index+"'>");
    $("[name=zip]:last").replaceWith("<input type='text' class='otherBusinessField' data-id='"+index+"' id='zip"+index+"' name='zip"+index+"'>");
    $("[name=stateOrProvince]:last").attr('name', 'stateOrProvince'+index).addClass('otherBusinessField');
    $("[name=officePhone]:last").replaceWith("<input class='otherBusinessField' type='text' data-id='"+index+"' id='officePhone"+index+"' name='officePhone"+index+"'>");
    $("[name=takesCallsStart]:last").attr('name', 'takesCallsStart' + index).addClass('otherBusinessField');
    $("[name=takesCallesEnd]:last").attr('name', 'takesCallesEnd' + index).addClass('otherBusinessField');
    $("[name=otherOffice]:last").find('.bootstrap-switch:last').replaceWith("<input type='checkbox' class='otherBusinessField' data-id='"+index+"' id='takesCallsStartSuffix"+index+"' name='takesCallsStartSuffix"+index+"'>");
    $("[name=otherOffice]:last").find('.bootstrap-switch:first').replaceWith("<input type='checkbox' class='otherBusinessField' data-id='"+index+"' id='takesCallsEndSuffix"+index+"' name='takesCallsEndSuffix"+index+"'>");

    $("[name=businessEmail]:last").replaceWith("<input type='text' data-id='"+index+"' id='businessEmail"+index+"' name='businessEmail2'>");
    $("[name=emailProcessedByMe]:last").replaceWith("<input type='checkbox' data-id='"+index+"' id='emailProcessedByMe"+index+"' name='emailProcessedByMe2'>");
    $("[name=emailProcessedByStaff]:last").replaceWith("<input type='checkbox' data-id='"+index+"' id='emailProcessedByStaff"+index+"' name='emailProcessedByStaff2'>");
    $("[name=emailRespondedBy]:last").replaceWith("<select id='emailRespondedBy"+index+"' name='emailRespondedBy2'>");
    //END change input names for other business location for validation

    $("#takesCallsStartSuffix"+index).bootstrapSwitch({onText:"AM", offText: "PM",onSwitchChange:takesCallsEvent});
    $("#takesCallsEndSuffix"+index).bootstrapSwitch({onText:"AM", offText: "PM", state:true, onSwitchChange:takesCallsEvent});
    $("[name=otherOffice]:last").find('.chosen-container').remove();
    if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        $('input').placeholder();
    }
    $('.zip').mask('99999-ZZZZ', {translation: {'Z': {pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true}}});
    /*$(".takesCallsStart").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 12});
    $(".takesCallsEnd").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 12});
    $(".takesCallsStartSuffix").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
    $(".takesCallsEndSuffix").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
    */
    updateStateOrProvinceList("", index-1, "");
    $("[name=stateOrProvince]:last").chosen({width: '100%'});
    $(".chosen-container.chosen-container-single").on("focusout", function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".takesCallsStart").blur();
        $(this).parent().find(".takesCallsEnd").blur();
        $(this).parent().find(".takesCallsStartSuffix").blur();
        $(this).parent().find(".takesCallsEndSuffix").blur();
        $(this).parent().find("[name=stateOrProvince]").blur();
    });

});
```

And the beginning and relevant parts of the associated HTML--selecting "Yes" on the final radio creates a new copy of the template above it:

```
                        <div id="BusinessBox" class="accordion_in">
                      <div class="acc_head">Business & Licensing
                        <div id="businessStatus" class="tabStatus"></div> 

                      </div>
                        <div class="acc_content">           
                            <div class="main_form_sec">             
                                <div class="main_formInr">
                                    <h3>Business and Licensing</h3>
                                    <h6><span>*</span> Required Information</h6>
                                    <div name="otherOffice">
                                    <h5>Office and Contact Information</h5>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <label>Primary Practice Company Name or DBA</label>
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list">                            
                                            <li>
                                                <input name="companyName" placeholder="Your practice name here" type="text" class="big"/>
                                            </li>                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list">                            
                                            <li>
                                                <label><span>*</span>Primary Office Street Address (Line 1)</label><input name="officeAddressLine1" id='officeAddressLine1' type="text" class="big_sml"/>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <label>Primary Office Street Address (Line 2) (Optional)</label><input name="officeAddressLine2" type="text" class="big_sml"/>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list">                            
                                            <li>
                                                <label><span>*</span>City</label><input id="city" name="city" type="text">
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <label><span>*</span>State/Territory/Province</label>
                                                <select name="stateOrProvince" id="stateOrProvince" class="select_list big selectBox">
                                                    <option>select</option>
                                                    <option>select</option>
                                                    <option>select</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <label><span>*</span>Zip/Postal Code</label><input id="zip" name="zip"  class="sml" type="text">
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="weelChairAccessible1" name="weelChairAccessible" type="checkbox" value="weelChairAccessible" name="chk">
                                                <label for="weelChairAccessible1">Office is wheelchair accessible (optional)</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="twoBlocksFromPublicTransport1" name="twoBlocksFromPublicTransport" type="checkbox" value="twoBlocksFromPublicTransport" name="chk">
                                                <label for="twoBlocksFromPublicTransport1">Office is within 2 blocks of public transportation (optional)</label>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">                           
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="line_height"> <span>*</span> Office Phone (Please entet the data with no punctuation)</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input name="officePhone" id="officePhone" placeholder="(NPA) NXX-XXXX" type="text">
                                            </li>                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">                           
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="line_height"> <span>*</span> My office takes calls between:</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                  <select name="takesCallsStart" class="select_list selectBox takesCallsStart" data-hasqtip="686">
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                                  </select>
                                                  <input id="takesCallsStartSuffix1"type="checkbox" value="AM" data-id="1" name="takesCallsStartSuffix" checked> 
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="line_height">and</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                              <select name="takesCallsEnd" class="select_list selectBox takesCallsEnd" data-hasqtip="688">
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                              </select>

                                              <input id="takesCallsEndSuffix1" data-id="1"  type="checkbox" name="takesCallsEndSuffix" checked> 
                                            </li>   
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">                           
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="line_height"> Fax (Please enter the data with no punctuation)</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="fax" name="fax" placeholder="(NPA) NXX-XXXX" maxlength="14" type="text">
                                            </li>                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">                           
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="line_height"> Alternate Office Phone (Please enter the data with no punctuation)</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="altOfficePhone" name="altOfficePhone" maxlength="14" placeholder="(NPA) NXX-XXXX" type="text">
                                            </li>                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list">
                                            <li>
                                                <label for="businessEmail"><span>*</span>Business Email Address</label><input name="businessEmail" id='businessEmail' class='businessEmail' type="text" class="big_sml" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>                  

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <label><span>*</span>Client emails are responded to by:</label>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="emailProcessedByMe" name="emailProcessedByMe" type="checkbox" value="emailProcessedByMe" checked>
                                                <label for="emailProcessedByMe">Me personally</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="emailProcessedByStaff1" name="emailProcessedByStaff" type="checkbox" value="emailProcessedByStaff">
                                                <label for="emailProcessedByStaff1">My staff</label>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>                  

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="form_colom_list2">                           
                                            <li>
                                                <label class="line_height"> <span>*</span> Number of busines days emails are responded to:</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <select name = 'emailRespondedBy' class="select_list selectBox">
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </li>                               
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul class="redioButtons otherOffices form_colom_list2">                         
                                            <li>
                                                <label> Do you have offices in other locations?</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="otherOfficeRadioYes1" type="radio" name="otherOfficeRadio1" class="css-checkbox" value="y">
                                                <label for="otherOfficeRadioYes1">Yes</label>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="radio" id="otherOfficeRadioNo1" name="otherOfficeRadio1" class="css-checkbox" value="n">
                                                <label for="otherOfficeRadioNo1">No</label>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
```

Comment: you need to show html and the click event you use this js code in

Comment: look as I understand .. when you ask user Do you have offices in other locations? and if he click y you need to give him another row with form to fill it with another office information .. right??

Comment: I would use closest() instead of using multiple parents so it is easier to understand.

Comment: ^^ i agree, i will change that.  but it's like the variable is immutable after the first time concat'd.  im very comfortable with jQuery, but it seems like im just missing something glaringly obvious.  like I said, the variable value logs correctly

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that one can't use the jQuery's `replaceWith()` method for recursive replacement.  Once the index 1 element is replaced, the `replaceWith()` method has nothing to match on (the original element has been replaced), so the iterator ran once, changed all the values, then stopped.